# Laravel route for view with an input form

Tags: php, forms, laravel, routes

using Laravel 5.3 I want to have a rout which directs to a view with a form to create a new object

I have these routes

```
//to show all lectures
Route::get('lectures', 'LecturesController@index');

//to show specific lecture
Route::get('lectures/{lecture}', 'LecturesController@show');

//to display form to create a new Lecture
Route::get('lectures/create', 'LecturesController@create');

//to handle process of creating a new lecture
Route::post('lectures/create','LecturesController@store');
```

All work find except the route which should display the form for adding new lecture.

```
public function create(){
    return view('lectures.create');
}
```

It doesn't even gets to the controller because when I go to address "localhost/lectures/create" I get these two exceptions:

```
ModelNotFoundException in Builder.php line 311:
No query results for model [App\Lecture].

NotFoundHttpException in Handler.php line 113:
No query results for model [App\Lecture].
```

I have no idea why it doesn't work when methods index, show and store works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have `Route::get('lectures/{lecture}', 'LecturesController@show');` AFTER `Route::get('lectures/create', 'LecturesController@create');`.  Laravel will match the first route and then stop so you're actually accessing `Route::get('lectures/{lecture}', 'LecturesController@show');` and in your show method `$lecture === 'create'`

Comment: Thank you! It works now! I didn't realize it goes through the routes sequentially.